# Cleaning Canon's print head tips

Tags: printer, cleaning

Printer in question: Canon Pixma iP3300 ... a relatively low grade model printer (otherwise, I wouldn't be doing something like this), has a [removable print head](http://www.markett.co.uk/images/print%20head%20template.bmp), and 4 cartridges that fit inside (C, M, Y, Black)

And one of the colours (cyan) is printing badly ... I tried most combinations of software features related to cleaning (regular clean, deep clean and the like) but to no avail. And since the local service is not working for a month or so (organizational restructuring, two companies merging ... temporarily, but that doesn't help me) I'm forced to try to clean it myself.

***So, I'm here looking for tips. What would be the best way to do it ?***
(wash it up, leave it in soaking water, some special fluids (alcohol ?) ... I'd like to do the job done somewhat economically reasonable so ...). I know most of you don't have this model at disposal, but doesn't matter ... the principles are the same ... I'll take any ideas you can give.

*The cyan in question is not completely blocked, but it prints significantly worse then it used to ... the lines are intermitted, the colour is fatigue ...*

Comment: p.s. I'll accept the answer which solves the problem. If no one does, (and I ruin the printer <-- no big shame anyway), I'll just accept the most voted one. But I want the one which (if) solves it, to get rep for helping; that's why I'm leaving the CW unckecked.

Comment: This is an ancient question, but I would not want new readers trying the accepted answer.  Another question has a detailed answer (happens to be my own), with proper instructions for how to do this: http://superuser.com/questions/1088315/how-do-i-clean-just-one-color-of-my-inkjet-printhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just spray some bathroom cleaner on a kitchen towel and touch the print head on to the kitchen towel.

If you want to run a cleaning solution through the print head use something less aggressive like [isopropyl alcohol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isopropyl_alcohol) or distilled water.

You can also spray some bathroom cleaner onto a sheet of thick paper and run it through the feeder to get rid of any muck on the print rollers.

Comment: bathroom cleaner - is that the stuff you clean the sink and the bathtub with, or ... ?

Comment: that's the stuff :)

Comment: Well, I didn't have any soft towels, so I drained the cleaner into a hankerchief and left the head on that for a bit. After which I flushed with a liter of destilled water (heated) ... it works a little better now ... will probably try it again once but it definitely works.

Comment: Bathroom cleaner would be low on my list of products I would get near a printhead.  Aside from distilled water and isopropyl alcohol, there is actual printhead cleaner you can pick up at places like office supply stores.