# Kodak esp 5020 new cartridge not printing

Tags: printer, inkjet-printer

Just installed new cartridges neither will print anything tried cleaning the print heads multiple times with no results and copying a b+w/color page multiple times then stuck my finger on them they are not dried out finally resorted to manually cleaning the print head with isopropyl alcohol which got me a couple of black spots and streaks along one edge.  Anyone with more printer experience have any other ideas?

Comment: When was the last time you successfully printed with this printer. Inkjets suck, they tend to dry out when not used regularly, and then the nozzles clog forever.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to revive an inkjet printer -- partially clogged/dried up?](http://superuser.com/questions/55907/how-to-revive-an-inkjet-printer-partially-clogged-dried-up), http://superuser.com/questions/94546/cleaning-canons-print-head-tips?rq=1, perhaps also see: [Best way to save ink in inkjet printer when rarely used?](http://superuser.com/questions/198005/best-way-to-save-ink-in-inkjet-printer-when-rarely-used?lq=1)

Comment: Techie007 less than 2 weeks ago