# Canon Pixma stops printing cyan

Tags: canon-pixma

Canon pixma MP450 doesn't print blue (cyan) any more . I've tried several 'deep clean' cycles without effect .
Could there be a possible 'cure' or is it bye bye printer ? That'd be a shame as assuming it was a lack of ink I've bought new cartridges !!

Comment: It's worth noting that the cartridges that come with most printers aren't full. Only 30% or thereabouts, so they generally don't last very long until you need to replace the first set..

Comment: If the cartridge isn't empty, per Jamund's comment, the answers on this question may help: http://superuser.com/questions/1088315/how-do-i-clean-just-one-color-of-my-inkjet-printhead

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any 2nd computer/laptop? Try printing from the other one.

Else, uninstall the printer driver by going to Control Panel > Programs & Features > select any Canon printer programs & fully uninstall them. If there is no Canon programs then go to Control Panel > Device & printers > Right click on your printer & select Remove device > Click yes. Then restart your PC & download & install the appropriate MP driver from here: http://www.canon.co.uk/support/consumer_products/products/fax__multifunctionals/inkjet/pixma_mp_series/pixma_mp450.aspx?type=drivers

Even if that doesn't work, replace your cartridge with a genuine one ;)