# Brother printer printing entirely blank pages

Tags: printing, troubleshooting, inkjet-printer, brother-printer

My Brother printer MFC-J615W goes through the normal noises of printing and prints the right number of pages but they all come out completely blank.

The black ink cartridge shows more than half the ink remaining. A couple of color cartridges are empty, one is new. Color printing behaves the same way: right noises, blank pages.

When printing a test page from the printer's menu, the same thing happens: normal printing noises followed by a blank page.

Running the printer's cleaning routine (two, three times) doesn't make a difference either.

I'm using OSX Sierra. I tried downloading the current drivers from Brother, which do exist for this version of mac, namely 10.12 (technically I'm running 10.12.6). I also tried deleting the printer and then reinstalling the drivers but its behaviour has not improved.

Can anything be done about this or should it be chucked out and never be seen by a human being again?

Comment: Guess: If the printer hasn't been used for some time, the ink in the cartridges may have dried out (has happened to me, though in a different ink jet printer). New cartridges would solve the problem, but possibly you want a printer that doesn't have this kind of problem in the first place...

Comment: Run the nozzle check print test to see whether it's capable of printing.  Printheads do get clogged, in which case a few cleaning cycles may not make a difference.  Let us know the result.  If it's a clogged printhead, there are a number of existing answers we can point you to on how to fix that.

Comment: Thank you. I can confirm none of the print test print anything. If you could point me to said unclogging answers it would be much appreciated.

Comment: @Norbert, just FYI, if you address a comment to a user with @, like I did here, they will get an alert to your post.  Otherwise, people will be aware of it only if they happen to stumble across it.  You'll find lots of instructions by Googling "printhead cleaning", or searching on that phrase here.  The easiest one for me to find here was one I wrote: [How do I clean just one color of my inkjet printhead?](https://superuser.com/a/1088443/364367) (ignore the question title).  Hope it helps.

Comment: @fixer1234, thank you for both tips.

Answer (score -1):

I ran the Cleaning tool option on the printer and it fixed the problem!

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by the "cleaning tool option" (physical cleaning tool, printer self-cleaning cycle, etc.)?  This is a bit vague to be helpful to other readers.

Comment: Please refer this link https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer help you to crate a good answer!