# HP Officejet Pro 8600 Plus not printing Magenta

Tags: printing, printer

I have an old [HP Officejet Pro 8600 Plus](https://support.hp.com/us-en/product/hp-officejet-pro-8600-plus-e-all-in-one-printer-series-n911/4322915). I just replaced all 4 ink cartridges. When I tried printing something in black and white, I noticed black was not printing.

I tried going to Setup > Tools > Clean Printhead.

- After the first level, black and magenta were not printing.
- After the second level, black and magenta were still not printing.
- After the third level, black was partially printing, magenta was not printing.

I tried running the entire cycle two more times, and black was printing perfectly, but magenta was still not printing. I tried replacing the magenta cartridge, but that didn't work either.

I looked up prices for a printhead, but they are over $200, more than the entire printer is worth at this point. My printer is out of warranty.

Any idea what else I can try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I clean just one color of my inkjet printhead?](https://superuser.com/questions/1088315/how-do-i-clean-just-one-color-of-my-inkjet-printhead) (question is slightly different but the solution is the same).

Answer (score 0):

If the issue is caused by dried ink, you could use a method similar to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6RodTteUqAY). As the video mentions, though, use it at your own risk because it could permanently damage the printhead.

In my case I used a [water syringe](https://www.cvs.com/shop/cvs-health-oral-syringe-2-tsp-10-ml-prodid-715154), and did the automated cleaning afterwards, and the printer worked again.