# Issues with HP DeskJet 5275/5200 All-in-One Ink Advantage

Tags: printing, printer, hardware-failure

I have hp deskjet 5275 purchased from Amazon(https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07BR8KMHH/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1). After around 150 pages of print it stopped functioning. Hp support link on the printer is of no use http://hp.com/support/djia5200. Ink level in my printer shows as below:
[image]

### Page I am trying to print:

[image]

### Printout I get:

[image]

### Another one which was in color:

[image]

### I have tried Aligning and clean print head from the printer portal, that also fails to print:

[image]

Considering ink levels are good, although they are very less considering I have just printed 150 pages and most of them were in black ink. Any suggestion on how this can be fixed?

Comment: [How do I clean just one color of my inkjet printhead?](https://superuser.com/a/1088443/364367) might help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks as if something is blocking the ink jets. I would start by cleaning the printheads, as follows:

> 1. Load the printer with plain white paper.
> 2. On the printer control panel, swipe left on the display, and then touch Setup .
> 3. Touch Tools, and then touch Clean Cartridges.
> 4. The printer prints a Print Quality Diagnostic report.

You may have to do this several times to clear the heads. This is a "feature" of inkjet printers.

This information is from an [HP support page](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05584456), which also mentions that inkjets should not be left switched on, but switched off with the power button. That way, when you switch it back on, it will go through a head cleaning cycle which will hopefully avoid these problems (but waste ink instead).

As this appears to be a business printer, I strongly recommend using a laser printer instead, and avoid any such issues. Lasers are also much faster and cheaper to run. Inkjets should only be used to print (expensive) photos on special (expensive) paper.

Comment: I have already tried clean cartridges option and it doesn't work. Please refer to the last image in the Question, that gets printed during Cartridge cleaning. After one time of cleaning, I am always getting blank pages.

Comment: You may need to clean more than once. Although it does bug me that the quality seems to get worse as the printer goes down the page.

Comment: I have done cleaning at-least 10+ times, now the cleaning gives just blank pages without any print.